# Google sign in doesnt work on production

Tags: android, google-signin

I have a problem with google sign in on production installation file. 
On debug installation everything is normal I can login into the application. But after changed on release i get null on account from google response. What could have been problem?

I worked with ("https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating"). every step same.

Comment: you need to have a configuration file with sha-1 key of release key, so only it will work on release build

Comment: @Madhur is it compulsary to get configuration file and add it to app folder. It seems that there is no need of it for launching app.

Comment: nope but Google sign in won't work without that config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a [configuration file](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) with,

**Android Signing Certificate SHA-1** with **release key** so only it will work with release build

Comment: i have it in app with sha1 of release keystore.

Comment: then how does your debug apk run with the release sha1

Comment: Surely there there is some problem with the SHA-1 with release key. Check if you have created the SHA-1 with the release key.

Comment: i needed to delete old file on console with api key so he can looks on that from conf file. thx a lot.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone using Firebase, you have to add the SHA-1 fingerprint to the **Firebase Console > Settings > Android App** page.

If you are using the Google Play Console, you can get this from the **Google Play Console > App Signing** page. There will be two of them (the one you signed your app with, and the one that Google signed your app with). You'll need to add both so you can test local release builds.

If you don't use the Play Store, you'll need to get the SHA-1 fingerprint from your `keystore` file using these directions: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: Updated app signing page title: *App Integrity*

Comment: I had the same issue. For debug releases I used SHA-1 generated by gradle. For production release you better take SHA-1 from Play Console.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct as this took me a while to work out here is an the answer with some extra help.

When you were debugging with firebase you uploaded a set of keys

SHA-1 and SHA-256 this will work with your test version but when you upload to production / Internal testing on the Google Play Console, Google Console will generate two more keys a SHA-1 and SHA-256 which have to be used if you want users who download your app to have access to Google Login.

You must add these to the Firebase → Project Settings → Android App → add new SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add SHA1 key from **Google Play Console -> Setup -> App Integrity -> App Signing** to **Firebase Console ->Project Settings -> General -> App**

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some extra info if anyone finds this.

1. When using Google Sign In with Firebase, you need to add the SHA1 in the Project Settings in Console.
2. If you're using debug version you also need to add another key for debug.
3. If your app is already is already published and you let google take care of the signing for you, it will change your keystore to another one. Your keystore will become a upload keystore which it uses for validating when you upload a new APK, but the production app will use another SHA1. You can either get the SHA1 from the console in Playstore (not firebase) or just go to Project Settings -> Integrations and link your firebase project to the Playstore.

IMPORTANT!
If you still have a problem, remember to retry everything after running
`flutter clean`

The dart tool might cache some configs and not use the correct settings for building the app so clean everything and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every answer above says the same thing. If you want to use google sign in from some environment, you need to add SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints from that environment in your firebase (or GCP) console.

1. If you're distributing your apk manually and not deploying it on some android marketplace like Google Play store, then the keys that you need to put in your firebase console are generated using the self-signing method mentioned on [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#self-signing_your_application). The pair keys are different for a debug apk and a release apk.
2. If you've put the apk on google play console then there play store signs your apk with its own pair of keys. You need to put those keys in firebase console as well. You copy these keys from the google play console by navigating to Release >> Setup >> App signing. You'll find those keys under "App signing key certificate". copy sha1 and sha256 from here and add them in project setting of your firebase app console.

Done. You don't need to upload a new apk. it will start working on the existing one.